# Путь становления веб программиста

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование

Веб программисты здесь есть? Совет дать можете?

Встал на путь становления веб программиста! Что изучать после `html` и `css`, `javascript` или `php`? Просто навыков программирования нет, даже в школе `basic` не изучал. Советовали следовать алгоритму `html>css>javascript>jquery>php` или же можно нарушить порядок, начав к примеру сразу с `php`.

Comment: Попробуйте уроки для начинающих и в php и js. php серверный язык, js для клиентской части. Что больше по душе придёт то первым и учите. Но если продолжите продвигаться дальше, то в любом случае оба языка придётся учить. В последнее время они очень тесно связаны.

Comment: Спасибо за совет я немного неправильно сформулировал вопрос, что изучать первым? Вот это я и имел в виду!

Comment: почитайте [похожий пост][1]

а так, можно php и пораньше изучить

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/214645/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0-2-3-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Изучайте параллельно, если вас интересуют именно эти языки. 
Азы учите в любом порядке, на это много времени не уйдет.

Comment: Спасибо за совет я немного неправильно сформулировал вопрос, что изучать первым? Вот это я и имел в виду!

Comment: Я же говорю: одновременно. Но если вам хочется именно порядок - HTML+CSS, PHP, JS, JQUERY